# Can't change column name when creating dataframe with list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension, tweepy

I'm currently working with Tweepy and I made a dataframe with this

```
df_user = pd.DataFrame([x.user.id, x.user.name, x.user.screen_name,
  x.user.location, x.user.created_at, x.user.followers_count, x.user.friends_count,
  x.user.verified] for x in result
)
```

The dataframe I got has 0, 1, 2, etc as the column names. When I wanted to change them, this is what I did

```
df_user = df_user.rename(columns={0:'userid', 1:'name', 2:'screenname', 3:'location', 4:'acccreated', 
5:'follower', 6:'friend', 7:'verified'})
```

Because when I tried

```
df_user = pd.DataFrame([x.user.id, x.user.name, x.user.screen_name,
  x.user.location, x.user.created_at, x.user.followers_count, x.user.friends_count,
  x.user.verified] for x in result, columns=['userid', 'name', 'screenname', 'location', 
  'acccreated','follower','friend','verified']
)
```

I got a syntax error at the for loop. I also tried putting the for statement inside the list, doesn't work either. Is there a way for doing both dataframe creation and changing column names in just one line?

Comment: do you still need help here or can this be closed?

Answer (score 0):

Just put them together for one line

`df = pd.DataFrame([x.user.id, x.user.name, x.user.screen_name, x.user.location, x.user.created_at, x.user.followers_count, x.user.friends_count, x.user.verified for x in result]).rename(columns={0:'userid', 1:'name', 2:'screenname', 3:'location', 4:'acccreated',  5:'follower', 6:'friend', 7:'verified'})`

Plus you got a syntax error because your `]` is in the wrong place. The `]` should be after `result` not `verified`